# How do I add cinematics to a Unity game with C#?

Tags: unity, c#, cutscene

I'm trying to develop a 3D game, and want to know the best way to go about adding cinematic or cut scenes that are triggered by a players proximity to certain objects.

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific problem you're trying to solve here. Is it detecting player proximity to an object? Or playing a video? Or firing off a series of events / animations using a script? Or authoring those animations in the first place? There's a lot that goes into a cinematic, so break it down for us and be specific: what do you have so far, what do you want, and what's the step you need help with? It's often better to ask multiple small, well-defined questions in separate posts if you need, rather than one mega-post that's too broad to answer in full.

Comment: Sorry I was asking how to add cinematics using the unity engine or another software like maya. I know it's possible using unity to create cut scenes but I'm not sure how I go about doing it. For example, I have a scene where there are 2 people in the environment, as your player approaches the other I wanted a cutscenes of the story to trigger and then once it's done to go back to the playable scene.

Comment: So, which part of that do you need help with? (Recapping my list above...) A: creating animations for the characters/camera. B: playing those animations in sequence with sounds/dialogue to convey a story. C: triggering this sequence upon the player's approach. D: pre-rendering this content to a video. E: returning to gameplay once the scene is over... as you can see, your description above covers multiple very different topics which could have very different answers. Try breaking the question down into the first step you don't know how to do, ask how to do that, then move on to the next step.

Comment: Okay thank you and sorry for making it so broad. yeah for now just creating the animations

Comment: Character animation is usually done in a 3D package like Maya / 3D Studio / etc. and then imported into the game. For details on that workflow, it may be best to ask in a user forum for the particular software tool you're using, or search animation tutorials for that tool.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on the sort of cutscene you want to play.

If it's a pre-rendered video you're after, then you can create a [Movie Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) and show that once a player has entered the specified trigger area. With this method it would just be enablinga plane once the player reaches a certain point, and then disable it again once the cut scene is finished.

If, on the other hand, you want to display a cutscene using your existing assets and cameras, then I'd recommend looking into the [Cinema Director](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19779) asset. It's a little pricey at $60, but I've been using it a while now and it's [well documented](http://www.cinema-suite.com/Documentation/CinemaDirector/CinemaDirectorDocumentation.pdf) and works nicely. With this method you'd need to direct the cutscene yourself, moving assets to the right point for the time frame you enter, and then play the cut scene once a player reaches a specified trigger.

Answer (score -2):

Your actually asking two questions:

1. How do I show cinematics, and
2. How do I trigger things by proximity.

The easiest way to show a cinematic is to show a pre-rendered video on a plane. The harder way involves controlling the camera and characters through animation, but what is shown can be dynamic, and interactive rather than premade.

For proximity, you can use colliders as triggers, or do continues distance checks.

You should explore one aspect of your problem at a time, and see which solution best fits your situation.

Comment: @Gnemlock I think it's safe to assume they meant "interactive" or "interactable" — I'd say in cases like this you can go ahead and make the edit. They're peer reviewed and easy enough to roll back if it turns out we erred.

Comment: You could have changed the "Your" that burns my eyes at the same time